# How to pause inside two (for) loops

Tags: java, android

I'm new here,new to Java,new to android studio, trying to make sliding puzzle ....
I want to put all my chunked small bitmap in my layout with a 300 ms pause for each chunk, I have two for loops that make my puzzle images, I tried some code that I found in this site, but all I get is a pause to the loop itself and not for the chunked images to build one after another with a small pause.
please help me .....
this is my two for loop one inside the other ....

```
        for (int i = 0; i < divide*divide;) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(PuzzleActivity.this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(params));
        globallinearLayout.addView(linearLayout);


        for (int j=0;j<divide;j++,i++) {
            ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(PuzzleActivity.this);
            BitmapDrawable bitmapdrawable = new 
            BitmapDrawable(chunkedImages.get(i));

            imageButton.setBackground(bitmapdrawable);

            imageButton.setId(i);
            linearLayout.addView(imageButton, imagebuttonparams);


        }
```

Comment: Did you try putting a sleep inside the nested for loop? If not, what did you try exactly to get the pause you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be posted after a delay, you could always use the `Handler`'s `postDelayed()` method. It accepts two parameters, a `Runnable` object and a delay time (in ms)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a delay (in this example 500ms):

```
for (int j=0;j<divide;j++,i++) {

  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
            ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(PuzzleActivity.this);
            BitmapDrawable bitmapdrawable = new 
            BitmapDrawable(chunkedImages.get(i));

            imageButton.setBackground(bitmapdrawable);

            imageButton.setId(i);
            linearLayout.addView(imageButton, imagebuttonparams);
                }
            },500*j);            
    }
}
```

Comment: all i get from this is a big time out ,instead of making each chunk with 300 ml time out.what am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Labelled Loop`:

```
outer: for (int i = 0; i < divide*divide;) {
   inner: for (int j=0;j<divide;j++,i++) {
     break outer;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all i get from this is a big time out ,instead of making each chunk with 300 ml time out.
i tried to add the Boolean to private from the app to throw an exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference .

what am doing wrong ?

```
    globallinearLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (for_chunk_builder = 0; for_chunk_builder < divide*divide;) {
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(PuzzleActivity.this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(params));
        globallinearLayout.addView(linearLayout);
        for (int j=0;j<divide;j++,for_chunk_builder++) {

            loopBoolean = false;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(PuzzleActivity.this);
                    BitmapDrawable bitmapdrawable = new
                            BitmapDrawable(chunkedImages.get(for_chunk_builder));

                    imageButton.setBackground(bitmapdrawable);

                    imageButton.setId(for_chunk_builder);
                    linearLayout.addView(imageButton, imagebuttonparams);
                    loopBoolean = true;

                }
            },300);

            while (loopBoolean.equals(false)){}

        }

    }

    for (int i=0;i<divide*divide;i++){


        if (game==2&&i==0) {
            alpha_ImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(i);
            alpha_ImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            alpha_ImageButton.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
        }

        else {
            ImageButton for_ImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(i);
            for_ImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
```